# automatically creating constructor and destructor in visual studio 2019 r

Tags: c++, class, destructor

visual studio 2019 doesn't create constructor and destructor when I want to create a class?
it shows the class empty with no constructor or destructor in header file or cpp file

Comment: That is correct.  You only need used-defined constructors/destructors if you have members that need special initialisation and/or clean-up.

Comment: excuse me could you clear it for me more ?^^

Comment: The generated class has no constructors / destructors because it has no members.  It's only after you add members that need special initialisation that the class __might__ need a constructor / destructor.  If members are added that do not need special initialisation then no user defined constructor / destructor are needed.  The compiler generates a default constructor / destructor that _"does-the-right-thing"_ if no special member initialization is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ class should only have a custom constructor or destructor if either of these do anything other than the default behavior. Therefore, these methods are not created automatically, as they are not needed most of the time.

To understand the reasoning behind this, you may want to read about the [Rule of Three, Five, Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (Be warned: Articles on `cppreference.com` are very technical, but there may be more friendly tutorials and articles about it. Just google "C++ rule of three"...).

Particularly, if your class needs do do anything special in a copy constructor or destructor (such as memory allocation and management), always consider the following:

1. Use one of the standard classes for managing memory, such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` to manage memory
2. Maybe split your class in multiple classes, one for managing each resource, and one for everything else, which uses the other class(es).

Finally, members of a class can now be initialized with default values directly in the class declaration, so default constructors are often not needed any more. Example:

```
// NEW style, using in-class initialization
class X
{
private:
  int _someMember = 0;
}
```

rather than

```
// OLD style, using a default constructor
class X
{
public:
  X() : _someMember(0) {}

private:
  int _someMember;
}
```

This means that many of your classes may not have any constructors or destructor at all.

Comment: I can't thank you enough ^^